# Vim: FuzzyFinder versus CommandT plugin?

Tags: vim, textmate

I've been searching for a "fuzzyfinder" plugin like the "Go to file" option on textmate.

I have found two plugins that seems to mimic this function:

- [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
- [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t)

Does anybody have any experience that can suggest one over the other? I'm mostly looking to know why did you pick one over the others. Basically to know if there oriented to a specific kind of public or the choice is just personal taste.

Obviously if you have another one please spit it out!

EDIT: Added requirements

I mostly work with Ruby and RoR projects (and tdd or bdd) so most times a lot of similar files exists, so moving between quickly and with fewer keystrokes the better. I also work with html, php, css and javascript (web development basically).

I'm also adding a link to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649187/vim-minibufexpl-versus-bufexplorer-plugins) (but on stackoverflow) because it could serve as a reference for what I'm looking with this question.

Comment: Just try them and see which you like better? You provide absolutely no requirements on which to base a reasonably objective recommendation.

Comment: I just wanted to hear why would you pick one or another. Also I wanted to know if they have some important difference (after reading about them I can't find any), but mostly I'd like to hear about other people experiences with them. 
My requirements aren't specific, that's why I didn't write about them, but I'm gonna add something to the question though.

Comment: Bad questions from *two years ago* on a *different site* are not supporting your question. This is a "*What's your favorite …*" questions specifically disallowed by the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask). Also [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3510/recommendations-for-the-best) and especially [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions) discussion on Meta are relevant here. Current moderation policy considers all but the most "interesting" questions unfit for this site, as they are inherently subjective.

Comment: Why complete strangers would choose from an arbitrarily shortened list of tools won't lead you anywhere. Try them and see which one is the most useful to you.

Comment: I didn't say they were "supporting" my question, I only gave it as a reference becuase I found the answers quite useful, because it make clearly that what was their main difference. Just to be clear why the question was closed. Is the issue just how the question if asked? I mean, it would be "acceptable" if I asked: "I'm looking for a vim plugin that helps to quickly navigate through different files with similar pathames/names?"

Comment: (Sorry, I pressed enter). Or are these kind of questions completely discouraged? (I read _both_ of your links, I still don't know).

Comment: What I understand from the rules is that asking for someone's preference is considered subjective and non-constructive. That kind of question has a tendency to attract useless base-less answers that no one really wants here. Asking for possible alternatives to another editor's feature is better because the answers are more factual (you get a list of links) but such questions have already been answered before and a simple google search will give you the same results anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Daniel Beck.

If your search only returned two plugins you didn't search in [the right place](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?&keywords=open%20files&order_by=rating&show_me=20&result_ptr=0).

I've tried both (and a few others) and finally settled on a third one with a lot less blog/reddit covering: [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) but I can't recommand it because you didn't say exactly what you want.

Just install all of them and see which is best for you.

If the opinions of strangers is important to you, this is vim.org's ranking of only a subset of candidates:

```
              | Ratings | Downloads 
--------------+---------+-----------
FuzzyFinder   |    1743 |     23181
--------------+---------+-----------
Command-T     |     609 |      8501
--------------+---------+-----------
LustyExplorer |     509 |      6348 
--------------+---------+-----------
CtrlP         |      92 |       275
--------------+---------+-----------
Molly         |      10 |       220
```

Comment: I looked there, I just found too many and still I can't find a "generic" way to name them. Fuzzy Finders maybe?

My question pointed to know why did you finally picked LustyExplorer instead the others, not necessarily do an objective recommendation. Maybe my question wasn't clear, or it's too subjective to be on stackexchange?

Comment: Exactly, I choose LE over other plugins because I liked it more. Your question is clear but too subjective: I can imagine 4 other members saying they like FF, CT, CP and Molly for whatever reason leaving you right were you were before asking the questions but with even more plugins to choose from. You **must** read each plugin's description/watch each screencast/look at each screenshot, do a preselection based on all that, then try each item in your shortlist, then choose one or none. Just like you did before choosing Vim over other editors or your particular model of Nike over other models.

Comment: It's actually helpful (at least to me) if you tell me that your choice was just a matter of taste, it also helped me because you introduced to me a totally new plugin that I didn't know about (I don't see the problem with that either). Don't get me wrong though; I'm not defending that the question is okay to be here, I've seen a lot in SE and most of them are useful (biased prolly, but useful).